# Unable to print from toString() Java

Tags: java, tostring

I used `toString()` to call `animal` but it didn't identify the `animal` variable, the following is my code.

```
package animals;


public class Animal {
    public String country;
    public String commonNam;
    public Animal(String name, String country){
        Animal animal = new Animal("Emu", "Australia");
    }

    public String toString(){
        Animal animal = new Animal("Emu", "Australia");
        return String.format("%d,%d",animal);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Animal Test");
        System.out.println(animal);
    }
}
```

The result I want is as follow:

```
Animal Test
Emu, Australia
```

Comment: create a instance at main method

Comment: Your question is not appropriate for this forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you gave above doesn't make much sense. Below is the corrected code. It will give you the result you want.

```
public class Animal {
    public String country;
    public String commonName;
    public Animal(String name, String country) {
        this.country = country;
        commonName = name;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s,%s",commonName,country);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Animal("Emu", "Australia");
        System.out.println("Animal Test");
        System.out.println(animal);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Animal Test
Emu,Australia
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am sorry to be so noob about this.

Comment: @TomSeku /* unfair */ -_-

Answer (score 1):

To get your desired result you have to pass an `object` of `Animal` class not the `Animal` class it self

try :

```
  System.out.println(new Animal("Emu", "Australia"));
```

instead of

```
  System.out.println(Animal);
```

Your contructor method should be:

```
public Animal(String name, String country){
this.commonNam=name;
this.country=country;
}
```

And toString method:

```
public String toString(){

return String.format("%s,%s",this.animal,this.country);

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, I am a super noob of in java

Comment: make those changes i mentioned and let me know if its work. and what part you want me  to be more specific? @TomSeku

Comment: Sorry but unknown resources

Comment: i did the same mistake as yours. now edited it should be `%s` not `%d` @TomSeku

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `System.out.println(Animal);` with some object of Animal i.e. :

```
System.out.println(new Animal("Emu", "Australia");
```

You will get `stack overflow` exception because you are creating a new instance in cunstructor.

It is because cunstructor is creating a new instance recursively and infinitely.

To get rid of that replace your code in constructor with this one.

```
public Animal(String name, String country) {
    this.commonNam = name;
    this.country = country;
}
```

Comment: Sorry when I try your, It said unknown sources.